# write INI files in jenkins with groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, ini

I am trying to create INI file through Jenkins groovy script. Is there any direct way to create INI file similar to what we have for YAML(writeYaml) and JSON(writeJSON) ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try `ini4j` library. Here is an [article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/839/how-to-read-parse-from-and-write-to-ini-files-easily-in-java) with both reading and writing examples. In Java it looks like that:

```
public class Index {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Wini ini = new Wini(new File("C:\\Users\\sdkca\\Desktop\\myinifile.ini"));
            ini.put("block_name", "property_name", "value");
            ini.put("block_name", "property_name_2", 45.6);
            ini.store();
        // To catch basically any error related to writing to the file
        // (The system cannot find the file specified)
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```